# Equivalent of addError in zend 2?

Tags: forms, validation, unique, zend-framework2

I've looked through the API but cannot seem to find: what's the equivalent of `Zend\Form\Element->addError($message)` in Zend 2? Or, how would I accomplish the same thing?

I have a registration field, where the username must be unique, so I'm waiting for the database to throw an exception, then flag the username field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$formElement->setMessges(array(
    'errorMessageKey' => 'Something strange happened, slap the admin!'
));
```

Comment: How would I set off the valid flag? And it seems to erase previous messages or get erased (depending on whether form validation or setMessage was called first)

Comment: What validator are you using?

Comment: I'm just doing random testing - like setMessages(array('random message')) and debugging variables. So I'll have a StringLength validator, and if I validate after I set the message, the message doesn't show. If I set the message, but the StringLength passes, isValid is true. But I want to add an error message, and set off the valid flag (which could be done easily with `addError` in zend 1)

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your problem. When you validate the form using the default validation classes, they either fail or succeed. You want to add a custom error message when the default validation fails or when it passes?

Comment: I want to append a custom error message if my own validation fails

Comment: Okay, in this case your best bet would be to write your own validator so it acts as one. Please refer to the manual to that: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.writing-validators.html Outside of that idea, you basically check if the form is valid and then if it is, THEN you do your manual controller validation and simply return the form with added error message as pointed out in the answer

Comment: Alright, sounds good. Will mark right answer after I do my testing (make sure it's working)

Answer (score 1):

I have did it like this for check the email is exist or not in controller.

```
 $postedarray  = $form->getData();
 $usersnameexist = $this->getUsersTable()->ISuseravailable($postedarray['email']);
 if($usersnameexist)
 {
    return array(
       'form' => $form,
       'errorMsg'=> 'Username already available please use other Username');
 }
```

then in view file

```
<?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('email'));?>
<?php  if($this->errorMsg) { ?> 
     <ul>
          <li><?php echo $this->errorMsg; ?></li>
     </ul>
<?php 
} 
?>
```